# Como cambiar y motrar el estado del componente padre en dos hijos por react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Basicamente es esto, tengo un componente padre que tiene dos hijos, uno de ellos cambia el estado del padre que se le envia por props y el otro hijo debe mostrar el estado cambiado. El problema es que cada hijo es un componente vista y se encuentran en diferentes rutas por lo que al querer redireccionar de un hijo a otro se pierde el estado. Usé location.href pero no funciona y Redirect de React Router ya no existe creo. ¿Hay alguna otra manera? Gracias por su ayuda.
Componente Padre:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Loader newYear={newYear} />
          {/* hijo que cambia la informacion en "/" */}
          <Countdown setNewYear={setNewYear} newYear={newYear} inputName={inputName} setInputName={setInputName} />
        </header>
      </div>
    } />
    {/* el otro hijo que debe mostrar la informacion en "/content"*/}
    <Route path="/content" element={<Message inputName={inputName} />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estuve viendo posibles soluciones y encontre el useNavigate que antes se llamaba useHistory y permite manejar las rutas. Podría ser que se utilice de esta manera:

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
//le asignas una variable
const navigate = useNavigate()
//redireccionar a otro componente
navigate("/content")
}
```

Si alguien tiene una mejor solución puede comentarla.